# How to prevent Rcpp from evaluating 'call' objects

Tags: r, rcpp

I need to simple wrapper to serialize arbitrary R objects from within Rcpp code. Below a simplified version of my code:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RawVector cpp_serialize(RObject x) {
  Rcpp::Function serialize = Rcpp::Environment::namespace_env("base")["serialize"];
  return serialize(x, R_NilValue);
}
```

This works great, however I found that for objects of class `call` the call gets evaluated before being serialized. How can I prevent this from happening? I just want to mimic `serialize()` in R.

```
# Works as intended
identical(serialize(iris, NULL), cpp_serialize(iris))

# Does not work: call is evaluated
call_object <- call("rnorm", 1000)
identical(serialize(call_object, NULL), cpp_serialize(call_object))
```

**Update**: I have a workaround in place (see below) but I am still very interested in a proper solution.

```
Rcpp::RawVector cpp_serialize(RObject x) {
  Rcpp::Environment env;
  env["MY_R_OBJECT"] = x;
  Rcpp::ExpressionVector expr("serialize(MY_R_OBJECT, NULL)");
  Rcpp::RawVector buf = Rcpp::Rcpp_eval(expr, env);
}
```

Comment: Create a `call` to `call` and then maybe just the top `call` will be evaluated? Just a random idea, I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: The workaround was on my mind too.  Even in the old JSS paper we show three different ways to get to `rnorm()`, you found two here.  The whole approach is still not what I would do -- see the answer I added by now.

Comment: You don't need workaround. You want to serialize to raw objects at the C level, _and there is a package giving you `serializeToRaw()` as a native C function_.  My answer below, downvoted twice (!!), uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've found an unexpected behavior in the `Rcpp::Function` class. An MRE:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject cpp_identity(RObject x) {
  Rcpp::Function identity("identity");
  return identity(x);
}

/*** R
quoted <- quote(print(1));
identity(quoted)
cpp_identity(quoted)
*/
```

gives

```
> quoted <- quote(print(1));

> identity(quoted)
print(1)

> cpp_identity(quoted)
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

This happens because Rcpp effectively performs this evaluation behind the scenes:

```
Rcpp_eval(Rf_lang2(Rf_install("identity"), x))
```

which is basically like

```
eval(call("identity", quoted))
```

but the call object is not 'protected' from evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: The question was *How does one serialize to Raw vectors from C*? The (compiled C) function `serializeToRaw()` in the [RApiSerialization](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rapiserialize.html) package providing R's own serialization code.  As the benchmark below shows, it is about three times faster than what was suggested above.

**Longer Answer**:  I would not recommend mucking around with `Rcpp::Function()` for this..   We **do** in fact provide a proper package for R which access to serialization: [RApiSerialization](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rapiserialize.html). It does not do much, but it exports exactly two function to serialize, and deserialize, from and to `RAW` which the [RcppRedis](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcppredis.html) package needs and uses.

So we can do the same here. I just called `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` to have a package 'jeroen' created, added the `LinkingTo:` and `Imports:` to DESCRIPTION and the `imports()` to NAMESPACE, and then this works:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RApiSerializeAPI.h>       // provides C API with serialization

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RawVector cpp_serialize(SEXP s) {
  Rcpp::RawVector x = serializeToRaw(s);    // from RApiSerialize
  return x;
}
```

It is basically a simpler version of what you have above.

And we can call that as you do:

```
testJeroen <- function() {
    ## Works as intended
    res <- identical(serialize(iris, NULL), cpp_serialize(iris))

    ## Didn't work above, works now
    call_object <- call("rnorm", 1000)
    res <- res && 
           identical(serialize(call_object, NULL), cpp_serialize(call_object))

    res
}
```

and lo and behold, it works:

```
R> library(jeroen)
Loading required package: RApiSerialize
R> testJeroen()
[1] TRUE
R>
```

So in short: if you don't want to muck with R, don't work with `Rcpp::Function()` objects.

**Benchmark**:  Using a simple

```
library(jeroen)             # package containing both functions from here 
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(cpp=cpp_serialize(iris),  # my suggestion
               env=env_serialize(iris))  # OP's suggestion, renamed
```

we get

```
edd@max:/tmp/jeroen$ Rscript tests/quick.R 
Loading required package: RApiSerialize
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval cld
  cpp 17.471 22.1225 28.0987 24.4975 26.4795 420.001   100  a 
  env 85.028 91.0055 94.8772 92.9465 94.9635 236.710   100   b
edd@max:/tmp/jeroen$
```

showing that the answer by OP is nearly three times slower.